# Работа инкремента в Java

Tags: java, java-8

Возник вопрос по поводу работы Java инкремента, я не могу понять логику как он считает его в этих выражения:

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 5;
    int d = 5;
    int e = 5;
    int f = 5;

    a += a++; //10
    b += b++ + ++b + b++; //24
    c = c++ + c++; //11
    d = d++ + ++d + d++ + ++d; //28
    e += e++ + ++e + e++ + ++e; //33
    f = f++; //5
```

Самое важное это выражение с переменной `a` и `f`, хочется понять как это работае в JVM

Comment: Шесть разных выражений как-то многовато для одного вопроса. Возможно будет лучше сосредоточиться на каком-то одном из них и расписать поподробнее почему результат показался Вам неожиданным.

Comment: Неожиданный результат в выражениях a, f, с. Они похожи, по этому думаю тут одно пояснение коснется их всех. Остальные выражение b, d, e привел для примера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пошагово, на примере `a += a++;`

1. Выражение транслируется в a = a + a++, далее правая часть вычисляется слева направо
2. a = (5) + a++ - вычисляется первое значение
3. a = (5) + (5)++ - вычисляется второе значение
4. a++ - переменная `a` инкрементируется и становится равной 6
5. a = (5) + (5) - считается вся правая часть, которая равна 10 и присваивается `a`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять это, вам нужно знать разницу между i++ и ++i. В первом случае сначала возвращаем значение i, а потом увеличиваем его на единицу, во втором - увеличиваем на единицу значение i и потом возвращаем его. После того как разберетесь с эти все будет ясно ;)

Comment: Тогда почему выражение с переменной 'f' потом не увеличивает на 1, а выражение с переменной 'с', где 2 операции инкремента увеличивает только на 1?

Comment: c = c++ + c++; //11 (c = 5 + 6) - в превом случае первый операнд берет значение до инкремента второй после инкремента, но только первого. С f, код вообще не имеет смысла, поскольку переменная примитив.